# Existence of solutions of matrix equation $A^4+I=O$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Is there an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ over **R**,  such that $A^4+I=O$ ? 
I know that $det(A^4)=(det(A))^4=det(-I)=(-1)^n\geq 0$. Then $n$ has to be even, and $det(A)\neq 0$. Therefore, $A$ is invertible. But I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: First, find a solution $A_2$ for $n=2$. Then the block matrix with copies of $A_2$ on the diagonal and $0$ elsewhere is a solution for all other even $n$.

Comment: Thank you! I finally understand what you mean!

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is even, consider a direct sum of $n/2$ copies of the $2\times2$ rotation matrix for an angle $\pi/4$.